# Passing a string from flask to angularjs

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask

I pass a variable from flask to a template like this

```
    @app.route('/')
    def respond():
        return render_template('index.html', bar='foo')
```

In angularjs controller attached to the body of that page I have a function like this:

```
$scope.init = function(bar){
        $scope.content = bar;
    }
```

I am trying to pass this variable from flask to angular in the template like this:

```
<body ng-init="init({{ bar|tojson|safe }})" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

But in the end the tag in DOM is messed up

```
<body ng-init="init("foo")" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

The problem with this are quotation marks. Browser cannot interpret them properly and the variable isn't passed.

So my question is how can I solve this? I don't want to make another http request from angular controller just to get that data.

edit.

```
<body ng-init="init('{{ bar }}')" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

seems to have fixed it

Comment: `<body ng-init="init('foo')" ng-controller="AppCtrl">` this should be fine..use single quote for inner variables..

Comment: `tojson` wraps strings in quotes.

Comment: @yotle does you problem solved?

Comment: @pankajparkar Yes, not exactly the way you told to fix it, but it's solved. Your and dirn's answers gave me an idea that worked. I edited the question so you can see how I did it

Comment: @yotle so would you mind if i add an answer?

Comment: go ahead @pankajparkar

Comment: @yotle I added the answer :p

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `'` while DOM attribute already has started with `"`

Double inside double qoute will break the DOM.

```
<body ng-init="init('{{ bar|tojson|safe }}')" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

Will render on DOM as

```
<body ng-init="init('foo')" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

Hope this could help you. Thanks.